# Why is strcpy appending junk characters to the end of a small fraction of strings?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I have a function that takes as its input a string containing a hyperlink and is attempting to output that same hyperlink except that if it contains a question mark, that character and any characters that follow it are purged.

First, I open a text file and read in a line containing a link and only a link like so:

```
FILE * ifp = fopen(raw_links,"r");
char link_to_filter[200];

if(ifp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open %s for writing\n", raw_links);
    exit(0);
}

while(fscanf(ifp,"%s", link_to_filter) == 1)
{
    add_link(a,link_to_filter, link_under_wget);
}; 

fclose(ifp);
```

Part of what add_link does is strip the unnecessary parts of the link after a question mark (like with xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/online-giving/step1.php?new=1) which are causing an issue with my calls to wget. It does this by feeding link_to_filter through this function remove_extra, seen below.

```
char * remove_extra(char * url)
{
    char * test = url;
    int total_size;

    test = strchr(url,'?');

    if (test != NULL)
    {
        total_size = test-url;
        url[total_size] = '\0';
    }

    return url;
}
```

at the end of remove_extra, upon returning from remove_extra and immediately prior to using strcpy a call to printf like so

```
printf("%s",url);
```

will print out what I expect to see (e.g. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/online-giving/step1.php without the '?' or trailing characters), but immediately after this block of code runs

```
struct node * temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
char * new_link = remove_extra(url);
temp->hyperlink =(char *)malloc(strlen(new_link) * sizeof(char));
strncpy(temp->hyperlink, new_link, strlen(new_link));
```

the result of a printf on member hyperlink occasionally has a single, junk character at the end (sometimes 'A' or 'Q' or '!', but always the same character corresponding to the same string). If this were happening with every link or with specific types of links, I could figure something out, 
but it's only for maybe every 20th link and it happens to links both short and long.

e.g.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/hr/ --> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/hr/!

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/windows-to-the-past/ --> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/windows-to-the-past/Q

This is happening both with strcpy and homemade string copy loops so I'm inclined to believe that it's not strcpy's fault, but I can't think of where else the error would lie.

Comment: Besides the unsafe string usage in remove_extra you should also use a safer form of fscanf with %as (and a string pointer address) or %199s.

Comment: Just for my own edification, what is unsafe about the string usage in remove_extra?

Comment: Well yes its not remove_extra, its the caller. It will search behind the allocated 200 bytes of the argument if there was no terminating \0 until then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compute `len` as the length of `src`, then the naive use of `strncpy` -- tempting though it might be -- is incorrect:

```
 size_t len = strlen(src);
 dest = malloc(len);       /* DON'T DO THIS */
 strncpy(dest, src, len);  /* DON'T DO THIS, EITHER */
```

`strncpy` copies exactly `len` bytes; it does *not* guarantee to put a NUL byte at the end. Since `len` is precisely the length of `src`, there is no NUL byte within the first `len` bytes of `src`, and no `NUL` byte will be inserted by `strncpy`.

If you had used `strcpy` instead (the supposedly "unsafe" interface):

```
strcpy(dest, src);
```

it would have been fine, except for the fact that `dest` is not big enough. What you really need to do is this:

```
dest = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);  /* Note: include space for the NUL */
strcpy(dest, src);
```

or, if you have the useful `strdup` function:

```
dest = strdup(src);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. And here I thought I was safe with the addition of the NUL byte in remove_extra. Newbie hubris, I suppose. In any case, thanks very much for the reponse.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly likely You forgot to copy a null terminator at the end of string, remember that strlen(str) gives the number of visible characters, You also need '\0' at the end.
You need to do

```
temp->hyperlink =(char *)malloc(strlen(new_link)+1);//char is one byte, sizeof(char)=1
```

and
`strcpy(temp->hyperlink, new_link);` Should work fine.

Why not use `strdup`?

Comment: `strdup` is non-standard. (That's not *necessarily* a reason not to use it.)